# What is the easiest method to copy files and directories in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried to copy some files from source to destination (flask app) in a dockerfile but it seems things are not working as expected when building the image. With last 2 line showing:

```
Step 3 : COPY pkl_objects/* /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier/pkl_objects/
No source files were specified
```

This is the docker file.

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

RUN pip install flask flask-wtf

COPY pkl_objects/* /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier/pkl_objects/
COPY static/* /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier/static/
COPY templates/* /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier/templates/


COPY app.py /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier
COPY reviews.sqlite /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier
COPY vectorizer.py /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier


WORKDIR /home/jovyan/work/movieclassifier
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
# ENV FLASK_DEBUG=0
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: What is the `docker build` command you are running? Also is there a `.dockerignore` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are no files in the pkl_objects folder, and when the wildcard (`*`) is expanded, it results in no source files being specified.

Maybe you could add an empty file in there, so that when the wildcard  picks up files, you at least get one source file.

Example file could be: `.nonempty` or something like that.

Comment: There are files in the pkl_object. I just can't figure out the best way to do this

Comment: You could specify the directory as the source, instead of using the wildcard. Then docker will copy all files from that directory. That's what it says in the docs anyway.